# Scipy minimize iterating past bounds

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize-minimize

I am trying to minimize a function of 3 input variables using scipy. The function reads like so-

```
def myfunc(x):
    x[0] = a
    x[1] = b
    x[2] = c
    n = f(a,b,c)
    return n

bound1 = (80,100)
bound2 = (10,20)
bound3 = (312,740)
guess = [a0,b0,c0]
bds = (bound1,bound2,bound3)
result = minimize(myfunc, guess,method='L-BFGS-B',bounds=bds)
```

The function I am trying to currently run reaches a minimum at `a=100`,`b=10`,`c=740`, which is at the end of the bounds.

The minimize function keeps trying to iterate past the end of bound 3 (gets to c0 value of `740.0000000149012` on its last iteration.

Is there any way to stop this from happening? i.e. stop the iteration at the actual end of my bound?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens due to *numerical-differentiation*, which itself is not only needed to infer the step-direction and size, but also to reason about *termination*.

In general you can't do much without being very careful in regards to whatever solver (and there are many backend-solvers) being used. The basic idea is to replace the *automatic numerical-differentiation* with one provided by you: this one then *respects those bounds* and must be careful about the solvers-internals, e.g. "how to reason about termination at this end".

### Fix A:

Your problem should *vanish automatically* when using: [Pull-request #10673](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/10673), which touches your configuration: `L-BFGS-B`.

It seems, this PR is not part of the current release [SciPy 1.4.1](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/releases/tag/v1.4.1) (as this was 2 months before the PR).

See also [#6026](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/6026), where a milestone of **1.5.0** is mentioned in regards to some changes including *respecting bounds in num-diff*.

For above PR, you will need to install scipy from the sources, which is:

- quite doable on **linux** (and maybe os x)
- **not something you should try on windows**!

  - trust me...

See the documentation if needed.

### Fix B:

Apart from that, as you are doing unconstrained-optimization (with variable-bounds) where more solver-backends are available (compared to constrained-optimization), you might try another solver, `trust-constr`, which has explicit support for this, see [#9098](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/9098).

Be careful to recognize, that you need to signal this explicitly when setting up the bounds!

Comment: Thanks, using `trust-constr` with `keep_feasible=True` worked for me. Could you point me to the exact documentation that I would need to install scipy from the GitHub source? I don't have much experience with Git. I have os x and use PyCharm.

Comment: [This is the doc-entry about building](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/building/)